# Packaging existing Class Library as a Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, .net, vsix

I have a class library with a number of custom code generators which I want to use in my work. Rather than doing all registry manipulations myself (or with regasm.exe) I would like to have a visual studio 2015 plugin that handles all that stuff. Unfortunately I couldn't find any relevant samples anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a few years back for a single file generator. The following blog entry has the details, and a pointer to the sample code:

```
  [Building a VSIX Deployable Single File Generator][1]
```

Note the sample's CodeGeneratorRegistrationAttibute class. This class is responsible for adding the registration info to your .pkgdef, and consequently is how the SFG is registered with the .VSIX.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2013/11/27/building-a-vsix-deployable-single-file-generator.aspx